# Why doesn't myArray print to innerHTML or console.log?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, console.log

Undoubtedly this is javascript 101, but why doesn't myArray print to innerHTML or console.log? I want a user to input something, and then for it to appear in the id="item" div. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="item">X</div>
<input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>

var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
myArray = [];
myArray.push(task);

document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = myArray;

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: have you tried initialize the array? var myArray = []; And can you set an innerHTML with an array? That seems a bit odd, should it not be myArray[0]?

Comment: Because you need to run the code AFTER the user changes the value in the input.

Comment: working for me ... https://jsfiddle.net/nzhc3gcc/ where is the javascript actually running?

Comment: @Rhumborl: So it wasn't running because there was nothing telling it to run and adding an event listener is what told it to print the user input?

Comment: Yes the event listener literally *listens* or waits for the button to be clicked...When it is clicked the function passed to it runs, in this case that function includes all the code you were trying to run initially and works as you had intended.

Comment: And if I want to run the event listener after the code, I just make my code a function and then put the event listener after the code? So, e.g., my code would be function add() {} for a to-do list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `onclick` event on the `add` button. so the script knows when to do run the function.
Because at the moment the script won't get called so it wont submit anything because it doesn't call up anything and wont run anything.

**Javascript**
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzhc3gcc/)

```js
  document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
    myArray = [];
    myArray.push(task);
    
    document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = myArray;
    });
```

```html
<div id="item">X</div>
<input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>
```

**Jquery**
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzhc3gcc/)

```js
 $('#add').on('click', function(){
      var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
      myArray = [];
      myArray.push(task);
    
      document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = myArray;
    
      console.log(myArray);
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item">X</div>
<input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.getElementById('add');
myArray = [];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  myArray.push(document.getElementById('task').value);
  document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = myArray;
  console.log(myArray);
  
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="item">X</div>
<input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create the function. And trigger the function on every clicking

```
<div id="item">X</div>
<input id="task"><button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Js

```
var myArray = [];
add =function ()
{
 var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
 myArray.push(task);
 alert(myArray);
}
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yv62w1jb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="item">X</div>
<input type="text" id="task"><button id="add" onclick="addText()">Add</button>
<script>
    var myArray =[];
    function addText() {
        var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
        myArray.push(task);
        document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = myArray;
        console.log(myArray);      
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```